# Why don't the child dialog receive the "DM_GETDEFID" message?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a child dialog that was created with `WS_CHILD`, as a child of a top level window. In the message loop I pass the handle to the top level window to `IsDialogMessage()`.

The window procedure for the top level window receives the `DM_GETDEFID` message but the child dialog never receives the `DM_GETDEFID` message.

//hwnd - handle to top level window

```
if(!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Why don't the child dialog receive the `DM_GETDEFID` message?

Comment: Did you set the `DS_CONTROL` style on the child dialog?

Comment: I'm not using a resource file. This is the code I used to create child dialog which contains controls `hStatic = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_STATIC, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 44, 44, 400, 400, hwnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);`. The child controls are parented by `hStatic`. The tab key works now but the enter key doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure a static control counts as a child dialog...

Comment: Can the first argument passed to `IsDialogMessage()` be the handle of a child dialog or does it have to be the handle to a top level window?

Comment: In Windows API terminology, a "child dialog" is literally a dialog (the kind you get with `CreateDialog()` or `DialogBox()`, window class `WC_DIALOG`) that's a child of another window. What you have is just a child window that has other child windows as children. Hijacking `WC_STATIC` like this is likely your issue (the static control's implementation might be wrecking things); either use `CreateDialog()` (because I don't know what you need to properly have a `WC_DIALOG` with `CreateWindow()`) or create a new window class for your containers instead.

Comment: I made some changes replaced the CreateWindowEx() with a resource file but It still doesn't work. I'm posting the whole code here

Comment: @andlabs Does the first argument to `IsDialogMessage()` have to be a top level window or can it be a child dialog or a window with the WS_CHILD style?

Comment: So now your child dialog is a dialog but it becomes apparent your top level window isn't. See the docs for `DM_GETDEFID`. **The DefDlgProc function processes this message**. You don't have a real dialog -> DefDlgProc is not being called.

Comment: I have updated the code to include 2 dialogs. The enter key still doesn't work

Comment: This is expected. The default push button is controlled by the outermost frame window. If you create a dialog as a child window, then it does not control the default push button.